# How do I use wavelet transform for feature extraction correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to classify words based on EMG signals using a support vector machine as my model. My dataset includes 15 classes (words) with 230 repetitions and 1000 features each. I already merged all files together to make it easier. The preprocessing steps I used are standard scaler and Principal Component Analysis. However, the accuracy I got was only 56%. I found online that using wavelet transform will help improve this but it made it worse instead. I only got around 6% accuracy! If you know what I'm doing wrong, can you please explain it to me? I attached my code below. I'm a beginner in machine learning as well so if you have the time, it would really help if you give detailed answers. Thank you so much!!

```
cf = pd.read_csv('EMG-TrainTestDataset.csv')

# Define input and output
X = cf.drop(axis=0, columns=['WORD'])
Y = cf.WORD

# Split into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1,random_state=82)

#Apply CWT for feature extraction
coeff, freqs = pywt.cwt(X_train,100,'gaus8')
X_train = np.array(coeff).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,X_train.shape[1])

coeff, freqs = pywt.cwt(X_test,100,'gaus8')
X_test = np.array(coeff).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,X_test.shape[1])

# Standardizing the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

#Apply Dimensionalitty reduction
pca = PCA()
X_train =pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)

#Create Model
model = SVC(kernel="linear",gamma=1,C=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Test using 10% testing dataset
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100)
```

Comment: C is a critical hyperparameter for SVM, and there is no indication that you have tuned it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to datascience.stackexchange.

In my experience using the `coeff` returned from the wavelet transformation directly - indeed doesn't work well for ml-pipelines.

My practice usually includes extracting different statistics out of them, like: percentiles, entropy, zero / mean crossings, etc..
Be creative and try them at random or at grid-search like pattern. Whenever in doubt - use less then more :)

This would also have the nice side-effect of reducing your relatively high dimentionality.